# Can't modify public variable inside value event listener Angular firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set a variable I have declared as public inside my class inside of a value event listener in firebase. Although, I am receiving the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'driverAssigned' of null.`

How do I set a public variable inside this firebase listener?

I have already tried making a callback function within the class to set my variable, but the error is the same.

```
export class InRideComponent implements OnInit {
    public driverAssigned: boolean;

    constructor(
      private fireb: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {
      const driverRef_str = "/queue/user";
      this.fireb.database.ref(driverRef_str).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          console.log("A driver has been assigned!");
          this.driverAssigned = true;
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of Javascript/Typescript context issue:

Although, i didn't checked this but you may want to try below:

```
this.fireb.database.ref(driverRef_str).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          console.log("A driver has been assigned!");
          this.driverAssigned = true;
        }
      }.bind(this));
```

Let me know, if it doesn't work:)

Comment: Since you are using Angular, I would recommend using the RxJS and [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) for consistency and don't forget to unsubscribe. Or remove the listener when you are done.